# Unable to get Netgear A7000 to work on 20.04 despite multiple attempts

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, ubuntu-drivers, netgear

I'm new to Linux and I'm trying to set up everything on my own (with manually created partitions for the first time). The installation process was smooth but I'm struggling to get my wifi adapter to work.

I'm using a Netgear Nighthawk AC1900 Wi-Fi USB Adapter (A7000) which works fine with Windows 10 but is not detected by Ubuntu 20.04

So far I've tried following steps mentioned in three different posts and none of them has worked for me so far:

1. First I tried this

   ```
   sudo apt-get install git dkms
   git clone https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8814au.git
   sudo dkms add ./rtl8814au 
   sudo dkms build -m rtl8814au -v 4.3.21
   sudo dkms install -m rtl8814au -v 4.3.21
   ```
2. Then I tried this

   ```
   sudo apt install dkms build-essential git
   git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
   cd rtl8812au
   sudo ./dkms-install.sh
   reboot
   ```
3. Finally I tried this

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
   cd rtl8812au/
   sudo dkms-install.sh
   ```

Am I missing something?

Also, idk if it is related in any way or if it matters but when I restart Ubuntu my screen goes completely blank and I have to force shutdown my desktop and boot again.

Looking forward to hearing from you all.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.04, the following worked for me:

```
$ sudo apt-get install dkms git
$ git clone -b v5.6.4.2 https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
$ cd rtl8812au
$ sudo make dkms_install
$ sudo reboot now
```